# transform x,y pixel valuesof image png into lat and long

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXjan.png)"I have multiple images, and each image has a position that is represented by points with x and y coordinates in pixels. I want to convert these coordinates to latitude and longitude but I don't have the zoom value.

Can Anyone help me how to convert these pixel positions into latitude and longitude coordinates

Comment: What do you mean by "images"? Map images? This question needs a lot of work to become any clear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

you can use plot digitizer software there are many open source

here is one

https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/